# Trouble removing duplicates from a LinkedList

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

For a linked list we are supposed to find duplicates in a linked list, however, the method that I've written seems to only go through once and does not remove all duplicates. Any idea on why it is doing that?

```
public void removeDuplicate(){
   LinkedListIterator iter = new LinkedListIterator();
   while(iter.hasNext()){
       Object j = iter.next();
       LinkedListIterator iter2 = iter;
       while(iter2.hasNext()){
           Object x = iter2.next();
           if(x.equals(j))
               iter2.remove();
       }
   }

   }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have tagged this homework?

Comment: Firstly your iterator `iter` has nothing to iterate over. Secondly `iter2` is a copy of the first when they need to be independent.

Answer (score 3):

when ever you need to remove a duplicates.
try to think of Set interface

and in your case use [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to maintain order.

Here is the code

```
Set uniqueList = new LinkedHashSet();
uniqueList.addAll(yourList);
System.out.println(uniqueList);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you need to use an iterator....

Your first problem is that you created an iterator, but not from your list.   If you have a list `myList` you create an iterator with `myList.iterator()`.

Your second problem is `LinkedListIterator iter2 = iter;`.  You want another different iterator; your statement makes both `iter2` and `iter` point to the same underlying instance.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedListIterator iter2 = iter;`

You only have one iterator. Also, this seems to be pseudocode, or you're not using the standard Java library.

All the suggestions for a Set instead of a List are of course valid, and would be the preferred way if this was not an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is simplier

```
List uniqueList = new LinkedList(new HashSet(list));
```

Comment: You loose the order like this and will get warnings since you're not specifying the generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Set<Foo> uniqueFoos = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>(myList);
myList.clear();
myList.addAll(uniqueFoos);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
LinkedListIterator iter2 = iter;
```

does not create a new iterator, but a new reference to the original iterator.  So when you call

```
iter2.hasNext()
```

in your `while` statement, it is advancing iter (because it is the same as iter2).  So when iter2 is done, so is iter.  They are the same.